# C# - Instance a class that returns JSON objects

Tags: c#, json, class, methods

I am learning C# and I made a console application that reads a text entry and searches an API that returns a value in JSON, then I show these values by console.
Now I need to pass this to a graphical environment and what I have done is create a class "MyClass" and within that class I have created a method "MyMethod" that will receive as a parameter a 15 digit number and will query the API (such as the console application did) and then return those values.

What I do not know is how to create the method correctly and how to instantiate it from another class because it generates errors.

My JSON:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "id": "20429683581",
        "name": "CINEPLEX S.A",
        "Condition": "HABIDO",
        "PLE": "02\/01\/2013",
        "lawyers": [
            {
                "type": "DNI",
                "numdoc": "07871885",
                "name": "PONCE PINTO ALEJANDRO EDUARDO",
                "date": "22\/08\/2000"
            },
            {
                "type": "DNI",
                "numdoc": "09333203",
                "name": "SORIANO BARRANTES JOSE FERNANDO",
                "date": "22\/09\/2008"
            }
        ],
        "workers": [
            {
                "time": "2017-07",
                "service": "8"
            },
            {
                "time": "2018-06",
                "service": "13"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have these defined classes:

```
public class Lawyer
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string numdoc { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string Condition { get; set; }
    public string PLE { get; set; }
    public List<Lawyer> lawyers { get; set; }
    public List<Worker> workers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

In a console application they worked well:

```
RootObject rootobject;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.example.com/api/?get=" + inid);
HttpWebResponse response;

try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }
    if (rootobject.success == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + rootobject.result.id);
        Console.WriteLine("NAME: " + rootobject.result.name);
        Console.WriteLine("CONDITION: " + rootobject.result.Condition);
        Console.WriteLine("PLE: " + rootobject.result.PLE);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
        Console.WriteLine("NOTHING");
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---------------");
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
}
```

I have since migrated to a GUI based application using `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass 
{
    public void MyMethod(int inRUC){
        RootObject rootobject;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.example.com/api/?get=" + inRUC);
        HttpWebResponse response;

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to get the value of a text entry in the graphic form and instantiate the class to get the results and print them in the text fields of the same form, but I do not know how to instantiate it correctly and how to place the values correctly, this is what I am currently trying: (txtRuc1) is my input of my form and EditText1 is my output of my form:

```
private void Button1_ClickBefore(object sboObject, SAPbouiCOM.SBOItemEventArg pVal, out bool BubbleEvent)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRuc1.Value.ToString()))
    {
        BubbleEvent = false;
    }
    else
    {
//Ok, I known that it is wrong
        BubbleEvent = true;
        MyClass obj = new Sunat();
        EditText1.Value = obj.MyMethod(txtRuc1.value).rootobject.result.name;
    }
}
```

What would be the correct form? Visual studio returns the error: Cannot convert "string" to "int" in these line:

```
obj.MyMethod(txtRuc1.value).rootobject.result.name
```

Comment: Could you put the json data and `EditText1` class code?

Comment: yes, I just put it

Comment: You need to parse the string into an int: `obj.MyMethod(int.Parse(txtRuc1.value)).rootobject.result.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, your `MyMethod` need to return `RootObject` instead of `void`

```
public RootObject MyMethod(int inRUC){
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.example.com/api/?get=" + inRUC);
    HttpWebResponse response;

    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    }
}
```

then the error was caused by `txtRuc1.value` might string value but the `MyMethod` method needs `int`.

so you can try to use `int.TryParse` method to parse the input value to `int` the pass it.

```
int para = 0;
int.TryParse(txtRuc1.value,out para);

EditText1.Value = obj.MyMethod(para).rootobject.result.name;
```

Comment: thank you!! a little question...This method will call one time to the API?, or will call API for every EditText2.value /EditText3.value ...?

Comment: when you call the method and pass the parameter you will call the API